# Loop through string to replace

Tags: asp.net, string, replace

need to look for instances of offsets in a string

```
<OFFSET_QX13Z@!:___>
```

where `___` is the offset in milliseconds (positive or negative) and `___` can be any number of digits (0-9)

So for example here is a string

```
"Estimated Delivery Date: Ending <OFFSET_QX13Z@!:-1209600000>\r\n
  :.Record Type\r\n
  : :.Stop Date Ending <OFFSET_QX13Z@!:-604800000>\r\n"
```

So I need to find every instance in the string then I need to replace the milliseconds with a date. I can do the number conversion, but I am not sure how to find each one and replace them.

So the result needs to look like:

```
"Estimated Delivery Date: Ending 9/10/2013\r\n
 :.Record Type\r\n
 : :.Stop Date Ending 9/17/2013\r\n"
```

The first is 2 weeks and the second is one week

Comment: It riped the string out. look here http://forums.asp.net/p/1938514/5517876.aspx?p=True&t=635156062815997457&pagenum=1

Comment: Which thing do you not know how to do?  Address one at a time, starting with the first.  Don't try to solve the problem all at once.

Comment: Simply posting your same question somewhere else doesn't help at all.

Comment: C# has some excellent string manipulation functions.  Read the documentation for String and see what's there.

Comment: Well then add a C# tag to your question.

Comment: I am not sure how to grab the milliseconds out and replace it. Not good at regex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about *asp.net* or *C#*, so I can not show you any code, just some ideas...

- You can use regular expressions. The regular expression `<OFFSET_QX13Z@!:(-?[0-9]+)>` should match all the offsets and give you both the position where it was found (for replacing it in the string) and the number of milliseconds (the part within `()`).
- Alternatively, just search for `<OFFSET_QX13Z@!:` and then for the next `>` after that, and add some offset to extract and replace the respective substring from the string.

Hope this helps...